# How can I create a css glow effect with javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, input

What I'm going after is a code that will gather all my text input fields and detect whether or not they have any input.  If so I'd like for there to be a glow effect added, if they're left empty or they delete the data and leave it empty I'd like for the glow effect to turn off.

So far from everything I've found this is what I came up with so far, it doesn't work of course, but it's the best I could try to rationalize.

```
function glow(){

        var text = document.getElementsByClassName('tex_inp01 tex_inp02');

        if (text.value ==null){
            text.style.boxShadow="#8fd7d2 0px 0px 22px";
            }

        else
            remove.style.boxShadow;

        }/**function**/
```

I used the .getElementsByClassName because the getElementsById didn't support multiple IDs as it seems, but if there's another more efficient way of gathering them all please share.

Comment: A textarea’s value can never be `null`. Did you mean `""`? Please check against empty strings with `===`. Also, `document.getElementsByClassName` returns an `HTMLCollection`, not an element. Also, what’s the deal with this strange pseudo-code `remove.style.boxShadow`?

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns `HTMLCollection` of elements.

Comment: Are you wanting to validate the inputs as the user is typing?

Comment: Why use JS for this?

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution can be adding class having glow with javascript:

```
var text = document.getElementsByClassName('tex_inp01 tex_inp02');
text[0].className = text[0].className + " glow";
```

[<kbd>**DEMO**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/3L0eL7yy/)

> **Note:** If you want to add glow class to each `input` then you have to iterate through loop and add class to each element. Because text is
>   `HTMLCollection` of elements.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the `value` of each element, not of the `HTMLCollection` returned by `document.getElementsByClassName`; `Array.prototype.forEach` can help with this. Then, a `value` can’t be `null`, but empty.

**Edit:** Wait a minute… you want the glow effect if the element *has* an input, right? Then your `if-else` statement is the wrong way around.

This is the correct function:

```
function glow() {
  "use strict";
  Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("tex_inp01 tex_inp02")).forEach(function(a) {
    if (a.value !== "") {
      a.style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 22px #8fd7d2";
    }
    else {
      a.style.boxShadow = "";
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of mistakes in your existing code (as presented in the question): (1) `text.value ==null` - do not check against null, because an inputs value will never be a null. Check its length. (2) `remove.style.boxShadow;` - I think that was a typo. It should have been `text.style.boxShadow = 'none'`.

> ..to be a glow effect added, if they're left empty or they delete the
>   data and leave it empty I'd like for the glow effect to turn off..

You can check if the input has been left empty by simply checking the length of the value. However, *to check if the input has been **entered and then deleted*** you will have to keep a flag to keep track of that. You can do that by hooking up the `change` event on `input`s and then setting a flag via `data` attribute. Later when you are checking each `input` for applying a style, along with the `length` also check this attribute to see if the `input` was edited out.

Here is a simple example putting together all of the above (*explanation in code comments*):

```js
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("a b"), // returns a collection of nodelist
    button = document.getElementById("btn");         // just for the demo
 
button.addEventListener("click", checkInputs);       // handle click event on button

[].forEach.call(inputs, function(elem) {             // iterate over all selected inputs
    elem.addEventListener("change", function() {     // handle change event
        this.setAttribute("data-dirty", true);       // set a data attribute to track..
    });                                              // .. a flag when it is changed
});

function checkInputs() { 
    [].forEach.call(inputs, function(elem) {           // iterate over selected inputs
        var isDirty = elem.getAttribute("data-dirty"); // check the dirty flag we set
  if ((elem.value.length > 0) || (isDirty)) {    // if empty or changed
          elem.style.boxShadow = "none";             // reset the style
        } else {
            elem.style.boxShadow = "#f00 0px 0px 5px"; // else apply shadow
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<input class="a b" /><br /><br /><input class="a b" /><br /><br />
<input class="a b" /><br /><br /><input class="a b" /><br /><br />
<button id="btn">Check</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery can help you as the following

```
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {


        $(".MyInput").bind('keypress', function () {
            $('.MyInput').css("boxShadow", "#8fd7d2 0px 0px 22px");
        });
        $(".MyInput").bind('keydown', function () {
            if ($(".MyInput").val() == "") {
                $('.MyInput').css("boxShadow", "none");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="" class="MyInput" />
```

this code working only online If you need to download Jquery library visit this
https://jquery.com/download/

Comment: _“Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected.”_ Source: [JavaScript tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info).

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to validate the inputs while the user is typing, you can use keyboard events to check the value of the input(s):

```
document.querySelector('input[type="text"]').addEventListener('keyup', 
    function(event){
        var element = event.target;

        if (element.value.trim() === '') {
            element.classList.add('empty');
        } else {
            element.classList.remove('empty');
        }
});
```

See fiddle for example: http://jsfiddle.net/LrpddL0q/.

Otherwise this could be implemented the same way without the `addEventListener` to perform as a one-off function.